# How to create column in DB with default value random string

Tags: postgresql, default-value, random

Can I create column in DB table (PostgreSQL) which have default value random string, and how ?

If is not possible, please let me know that.

Comment: please ask again for MySQL if you need an answer for that RDBMS too

Comment: UUID solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684011/242933

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PostgreSQL example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_random_text(
    length integer
)
RETURNS text AS
$body$
WITH chars AS (
    SELECT unnest(string_to_array('A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9', ' ')) AS _char
),
charlist AS
(
    SELECT _char FROM chars ORDER BY random() LIMIT $1
)
SELECT string_agg(_char, '')
FROM charlist
;
$body$
LANGUAGE sql;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_test;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_test (
    id serial,
    data text default f_random_text(12)
);


INSERT INTO tmp_test
VALUES 
    (DEFAULT, DEFAULT),
    (DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
;


SELECT * FROM tmp_test;

 id |     data
----+--------------
  1 | RYMUJH4E0NIQ
  2 | 7U4029BOKAEJ
(2 rows)
```

Apparently you can do this.  (Of course, you can add other characters as well, or use other random string generator as well - like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4566583/246260), for example.)

Comment: SELECT md5(random()::text); - That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 27):

The solution is (for PGSQL):

```
alter TABLE users ADD column register_key text NOT NULL default md5(random()::text);
```

Comment: This is a beautiful trick!

Comment: if you need to limit you can use this: ```alter TABLE users ADD column register_key text NOT NULL default substring(md5(random()::text), 0, 8);```